# Array.Filter and find not giving error angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list and I just want to filter. Array.find and filter are all producing errors.

Function :

```
 setSupplierDetails(supplierId) {
const supplier = this.suppliers.filter(tempSupplier => tempSupplier.id === supplierId)[0];
this.supplierName = supplier.supplierName;
```

}
Error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at AddEditRestockComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/restock/add-edit-restock/add-edit-restock.component.ts.AddEditRestockComponent.setProductRelatedInfo
```

Comment: Apparently, `this.suppliers` is not defined. Make sure that it is not only declared but also initialized (e.g. `suppliers: SomeClass[] = [];`).

Comment: post the `this.suppliers`

Comment: I found the answer. I made the supplierId that comes through the setSupplierDetails(supplierId) as a number which I realised was causing the problem.
setSupplierDetails(supplierId) {
const supplier = this.suppliers.filter(tempSupplier => tempSupplier.id === +supplierId)[0];
this.supplierName = supplier.supplierName;

Answer (score 0):

This should occur if your array is not initialized, in order to handle initalize your array

```
suppliers: SomeClass[] = [];
```

and inside the method

```
setSupplierDetails(supplierId) {
if(this.suppliers && this.suppliers.length > 0){
const supplier = this.suppliers.filter(tempSupplier => tempSupplier.id === supplierId)[0];
}
```